# subscribe in Observable + formControl Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I need to display the data returned from the FireStore in the screen fields when loaded, but **buildForm ()** is called before the **Subscribe**, so it does not display the data returned from the FireStore in the fields on the screen.

**perfil-model.ts:**

```
export class Perfil {
    nome: string;
}
```

**authService.ts:**

```
getPerfil() {
    return this.afs.doc<Perfil>(`perfil/${this.id}`)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(p => {
        return { ...p.payload.data() };
      });
  }
```

**perfilUser.component.ts:**

```
  perfil: Perfil = new Perfil();
  perfilForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    const subscribe = this.authService
    .getPerfil()
    .subscribe((p: any) => {
      subscribe.unsubscribe();
      this.perfil = p;
    })

    this.buildForm();
  }

  buildForm() {
    this.perfilForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      nome: this.perfil.nome,
    });
  }
```

**perfilUser.component.html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="perfilForm" novalidade>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <label for="name">Nome*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="nome" placeholder="Nome">
          </div>
</form>
```

I checked and are returning FireStore values, but I'm not able to return the screen.

Comment: initialize the form in `constructor` with default values, then while subscribing to observable change the form fields with `this.perfilForm.patchValue()`

Comment: @Hareesh Why do we need in constructor? Putting it outside should work too. if constructor, why not ngOnInit?

Answer (score 1):

use patchValue inside the subscribe

```
this.authService
    .getPerfil()
    .subscribe((p: any) => {
      this.perfilForm.patchValue({'nome' : p.nome})
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, it works that way too, but I'll look at the most correct method ... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the observable to populate your form, you have to call the `buildForm` inside the `subscribe` or at least assign values inside the `subscribe`. Here is an example

perfil.component.ts

```
nome:string;
constuctor(){
    this.perfilForm = new FormGroup({
       "nome": new FormControl(this.nome)
    });
}    

ngOnInit() {
    const subscribe = this.authService
    .getPerfil()
    .subscribe((p: any) => {
         subscribe.unsubscribe();
         this.nome = p.nome;
    })
  }
```

perfil.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="perfilForm" novalidade>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <label for="name">Nome*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="nome" placeholder="Nome" [(ngModel)]="nome">
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i thinks `formControlName` doing the data binding same as `[(ngModel)]`, both don't work together.

Comment: Sorry, but it's working along with [(ngModel)], now it's displaying the data on the screen, Thanks!

Comment: @Hareesh 
if you do not enter value in the field at save time, the object comes with undefined fields instead of string.

Example: {'name': undefined, 'city': undefined, .....}

It should be: {'name', "", 'city' "", .....}

Comment: @Safiyya 
if I save the empty fields, there is an error when saving ... 
I am sending this.perfilForm.value parameter, 
fields are not as string are as undefined Example: {'name': undefined, 'city': undefined, .....} It should be: {'name', "", 'city' "", .....}

Comment: @LuizCardoso how do you save? Did you add `(submit)="save()"` ? Can you share that code too?

Answer (score 0):

### when I leave some blank field is not saving as an empty string and error occurs

```
ERROR Error: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field administrador)
    at new FirestoreError (error.js:149)
    at ParseContext.createError (user_data_converter.js:162)
    at UserDataConverter.parseScalarValue (user_data_converter.js:439)
    at UserDataConverter.parseData (user_data_converter.js:339)
    at eval (user_data_converter.js:362)
    at Object.forEach [as c] (obj.js:49)
    at UserDataConverter.parseObject (user_data_converter.js:361)
    at UserDataConverter.parseData (user_data_converter.js:331)
    at UserDataConverter.parseSetData (user_data_converter.js:212)
    at DocumentReference.set (database.js:489)
```

**perfilUser.component.html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="perfilForm" novalidade>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
    <label for="name">Nome*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="perfil.nome" formControlName="nome" placeholder="Nome completo">
  </div>

<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" (click)="saveProfile()">Save</button>

</form>
```

**perfilUser.component.ts:**

```
perfil: Perfil = new Perfil();

  saveProfile() {
    this.authService.createProfile(this.perfilForm.value);
  }
```

**authService.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  perfil: Observable<Perfil[]>;
  userId: string;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.userId = user.uid;
      }
    })
}

createProfile(perfil: Perfil) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<Perfil> = this.afs.doc(`perfil/${perfil.userId}`);
    return userRef.set(perfil);
  }
```

**perfilModel.ts:**

```
export class Perfil {
    nome: string;
    ..... : string;
    ..... : string;
}
```

**the rest of the code is at the beginning of the question**